# cp with a single argument containing wildcards

Tags: shell, wildcards, cp, arguments

If I have the following 2 files and 1 folder:

```
someuser@computer:~/Desktop/test$ ls -l
total 340
-rw-r--r-- 1 someuser someuser  45082 ago  5 09:56 file1.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 someuser someuser 291836 ago  5 09:56 file2.pdf
drwxrwxr-x 2 someuser someuser   4096 ago  5 09:56 this_is_a_folder.pdf
```

And I run the following command (notice that I ommit the destination):

```
cp *.pdf
```

`file1.pdf` and `file2.pdf` are copied into the `this_is_a_folder.pdf` folder.

```
someuser@computer00:~/Desktop/test$ ls this_is_a_folder.pdf/
file1.pdf  file2.pdf
```

Obviously `*.pdf` is expanding into matching items, so it's equivalent to

```
cp file1.pdf file2.pdf this_is_a_folder.pdf
```

... and as `this_is_a_folder.pdf` is a folder, then the two files are copied to it.

**Is this a bug ?**

It's obviously a side effect of wildcard expansion and it's not what I would expect to happen.

I would have expected a `missing destination file` **error**.

Comment: Run `echo cp *.pdf` to see what gets executed. You omitted nothing.

Comment: The answer to "have I found a bug?" when you are seeing weird behavior in a basic utility like `cp`, with somewhere around 99% certainty, is "no". If it was a bug, you'd almost certainly not be the first to run into it; while existing features might be exercised rarely, it's pretty safe to say that anything new will be thoroughly tested by the developers.

Comment: You understand what the shell's wildcard expansion is doing. Why then would you have expected a `missing destination file` error?

Comment: @LarsH Principle of less surprise ? I understand that **after** it happend to me, not defore.

Comment: Principle of least surprise? What should `ls *.pdf` expand to in such a scenario, or `for f in *.pdf; do ... done`? I'd prefer wildcards expand to the same things regardless of command.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The expanding is OK, but obviously a person that executes `cp *.pdf` is not expecting it to copy some files to an uknown folder.

Comment: So how would `cp` know that you used shell wildcard globbing? How would it know that you want some behavior different from e.g. `ls`? What if you really *wanted* to copy all files and subdirectories with names ending in .pdf into a subdirectory named `all.my.pdf`? Comments aren't meant for discussion, but I'd say it is *far* from "obvious" that what you are proposing is better or more reasonable to expect. (I for one rather memorize one rule, that any wildcard glob will expand to everything that glob matches and I better deal with it, than one rule per command!)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I used to see it like this: in `cp *.pdf dest_folder`, `*.pdf` is the SOURCE and `dest_folder` is the DESTINY. If I accidentally ran `cp *.pdf`, I ommitted the DESTINY, and only provided the SOURCE, which should raise an error.

Comment: Which it would have, if `*.pdf` had not expanded to include a valid destination location at the end of the list, as exemplified in the answers already.

Comment: "Principle of least surprise" is a valid point, but it begs the question, why should that behavior be surprising? And yes I can see why it surprised you at first, especially if you didn't know that wildcards are expanded separately by the shell; but, given that fact, it's certainly not a bug in cp, and it's hard to see how cp could be designed differently to decrease surprise. Changes that *would* decrease surprise would be (a) don't name a directory `something.pdf`; (b) don't use a wildcard pattern, such as `*.pdf`, that could match an existing directory; or (c) use `-t` as @Braiam said.

Comment: @LarsH Something is certain: If it happens again, I will no longer be surprised.

Comment: a shell (`bash`, `sh`, `zsh`, ...) is a _command line **interpreter**_, so it interprets your commands and then executes them. So the command you typed is not always the command that will be executed. And the real command can't know what did you really type (in this instance, `cp` only sees `file1.pdf`, `file2.pdf` and `this_is_a_folder.pdf`, not your wildcard.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is not a bug in the `cp` command. When you enter `cp *.pdf`, `cp` never sees the actual wildcards because the *wildcards are expanded by `bash`, not by `cp`*. How will `cp` know that you have entered only one argument? *This is a side effect of bash wildcards and cannot be called a bug.*

Comment: `s/bash/shell/g`

Answer (score 23):

You seem to understand what is happening perfectly well. In your example, `*pdf` indeed expands to `file1.pdf file2.pdf this_is_a_folder.pdf`. I don't see what's confusing you. `cp` is doing exactly what it should, you are telling it to copy `file1.pdf` and `file2.pdf` into `this_is_a_folder.pdf` and that is exactly what it is doing. There is no bug, it is working as advertised.

Since your folder's name ends in `.pdf`, it is included in `*.pdf` and since it is a folder and the last argument (sorted alphabetically), `cp` copies the files into it. To get the behavior you expect, you need to protect the wildcard from the shell so it is not expanded before `cp` sees it:

```
$ cp "*pdf"
cp: missing destination file operand after `*pdf'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
```

Note that in this case, the wildcard is not expanded so `cp` is actually looking for a file called `*.pdf`. So even if you were to call it with a directory as the last argument (`cp "*.pdf" foo/`) it would complain about `cannot stat '*.pdf': No such file or directory`. You will also see your expected behavior if you try `cp *pdf` in a directory that only contains *one* file that ends in `.pdf` because `*.pdf` will be expanded to only one argument:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Aug  5 16:56 file1.pdf
$ cp *pdf
cp: missing destination file operand after `file1.pdf'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
```

Also compare with this:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 terdon terdon 0 Aug  5 16:56 a_folder.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Aug  5 16:56 file1.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Aug  5 16:56 file2.pdf
$ cp *pdf
cp: target `file2.pdf' is not a directory
```

Here, since the folder's name begins with an `a`, `*.pdf` is expanded to:
`a_folder.pdf  file1.pdf  file2.pdf`. Therefore, the `cp` command actually being run is

```
cp a_folder.pdf  file1.pdf  file2.pdf
```

Which returns an error because the last argument is not a directory.

Comment: But by using quoting in `cp "*pdf"`, even if you included a destination argument, the asterisk never gets expanded and you will get a "no such file" message unless you have one named literally "*pdf".

Comment: @DennisWilliamson yes indeed, but it gives the error the OP expected, hence it displays the expected behavior.

Answer (score 9):

As the other answers already pointed out, bash expands the wildcard and then passes what it sees to `cp`. In your case, `cp` sees `file1.pdf file2.pdf this_is_a_folder.pdf`. Now let's prevent it.

- **Don't use wildcards.**
- Use the `-t`, `--target-directory` switch and specify the target.
- Always declare at the very end a destination after using a wildcard.

  ```
  cp *.pdf /I/want/to/copy/files/here
  ```

Answer (score 8):

It's not a bug, it's a side-effect doing of wildcard expansion once in the shell rather than implementing it in every program.

Now, there are some *much stranger* ways you can trip yourself up with this, especially by creating files whose names start with "-". For example (in an empty directory):

```
$ touch -- --version
$ ls
--version
$ rm *
rm (coreutils) 5.2.1
Written by Paul Rubin, David MacKenzie, Richard Stallman, and Jim Meyering.

Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ ls
--version
```

The wildcard '*' expands to the filename which gets interpreted as a switch.

You can also cause chaos by putting spaces, tabs and newlines in file names.

Comment: This could also be a great demonstration of why you should use `ls` and not `ls *`.

Answer (score 4):

If the last part parameter is a directory, `cp` will copy the specified files to it. It does not care if you named your directory `foo.pdf` (why such a name?!). Wildcard expansion is based on the file name (or directory name), not the file type.

With two arguments, the target can be either a file or directory. In the case of a file, the target file is removed and replaced by a copy of the source file. If the target is a directory, a copy of the source file is placed in that directory.
Note one of the given synopsis:

```
cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
```

With three or more arguments, the target is treated as a directory:

```
cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
```

Comment: The problem is that I ran `cp *.pdf` ... not `cp *.pdf this_is_a_folder.pdf`

Comment: @user1598390 Glob expansion is done by the shell, therefore `this_is_a_folder.pdf` is implied by `*.pdf`. `cp` does not know that you only want to copy a set of files.

Comment: @user1598390: Why is that a problem? (Or: why is that unexpected?)